# how to understand First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty in rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to rails and just ran into this issue while trying to access :  `http://localhost:3000/bookings/1/edit` which leads to :**First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty** I have looked through quiet a few posts, some of them didn't define new action or edit action which i have done. but error still occurs. Any clues ?

```
      object      = record.is_a?(Array) ? record.last : record
      raise ArgumentError, "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" unless object
      object_name = options[:as] || model_name_from_record_or_class(object).param_key
      apply_form_for_options!(record, object, options)
```

routes:

```
get    'booknow'   => 'bookings#new'
  resources :bookings
  resources :users do
```

views/bookings/edit.html.erb: `<%= form_for (@booking) do |f| %>`

controller:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @booking = Booking.all
  end

  def show
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
  end

  def create
    @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)    # Not the final implementation!
    if @booking.save
      flash[:success] = "You have submited the information successfully!"
      redirect_to @booking
    else
      render 'new'
    end

  def edit
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  end
end


  private
  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:date_of_tour, :hotel_name, :phone_number, :number_of_pax, :pick_up_time )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error simply means that the first argument to `form_for` (@booking) was nil

The clue here is the double `end` after the `edit` method. One of these is actually a misplaced `end` for the `create` method with the result that the `edit` method is defined only once the create method has been called. If not rails stills renders the correct template, but since the `edit` method wasn't called `@booking` is not set.

Comment: It's working now, Thank you so much . That's a shame , this is not the first time i encounter with this kind of issue , Do you have any suggestions that can avoid this kind of typo ? What is the best way to debug this kind of issue ? Thank you again! :)

Comment: @Snailwalker the double end at the end of the edit method was a dead giveaway for me - a non indented end should only appear at the end of the class

Comment: you've got a very sharp eye there. Thanks :) You are the man !

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem offhand, but this error indicates that the `form_for` method is getting an uninitialized variable. So I'd start by adding a `puts #{@booking.inspect}` statement at the end of the controller `edit` action, and then copy the same puts statement to the ERB template before the `form_for` call, so you can verify that the variable is being passed in correctly.

Your routes shouldn't be relevant, as long as you make a request to that URL and the server logs / console output shows that you're getting to the right controller action and view.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion , i think i need to go through  documentation about debugging rails .

Comment: Yeah, agreed. You'll spend a lot of your time (probably most of your time) debugging. But debugging doesn't need to be super  fancy; simply sprinkling a few `puts` statements around your code is very often enough to get you the information you need.